# Why won't the Eden Project monument unlock?

Tags: cities-skylines

I'm trying to construct the Eden Project.  I created the Cathedral of Plentitude (it's in the picture),  and it's operational and has visitors.
Why is the Eden Project still locked? How can I unlock it?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each [monument](http://www.skylineswiki.com/Monuments) requries building a specific unique building from each of the 6 tiers of [unique buildings](http://www.skylineswiki.com/Unique_buildings).

To unlock the Eden Project, you also need to build these additional unique buildings:

- Statue of Industry
- Friendly Neighborhood Park
- Official Park
- Business Park
- Servicing Services Offices.

Comment: Yes, it appears the tooltips for monument unlocks are currently bugged and not updating to show what you actually need to build.

Comment: OK, yeah, that bug is frustrating...like the 30 services building one..hard to really tell whats left.  I dont know what some of these are (like Friendly Neighborhood Park)....guess there is some wikia digging in my future.